# How to fetch recent messages from Kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Do we have any option like fetching recent 10/20/ etc., messages from Kafka topic. I can see --from-beginning option to fetch all messages from the topic but if I want to fetch only few messages first, last, middle or latest 10. do we have some options?

Comment: What client are you using? Is this part of a program you are writing, or you just want to explore the data from the command line?

Comment: Please go through this document for understanding `kafka Offsets`.
https://www.learningjournal.guru/courses/kafka/kafka-foundation-training/offset-management/

Answer (score 10):

### First N messages

You can use `--max-messages N` in order to fetch the first `N` messages of a topic.

For example, to get the first 10 messages, run

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --from-beginning  --max-messages 10
```

### Next N messages

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --max-messages 10
```

### Last N messages

To get the last N messages, you need to define a specific partition and the offset:

```
bin/kafka-simple-consumer-shell.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test--partition testPartition --offset yourOffset
```

### M to N messages

Again, for this case you'd have to define both the partition and the offset.
For example, you can run the following in order to get N messages starting from an offset of your choice:

```
bin/kafka-simple-consumer-shell.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test--partition testPartition --offset yourOffset --max-messages 10
```

If you don't want to stick to the binaries, I would suggest you to use [`kt`](https://github.com/fgeller/kt) which is a Kafka command line tool with more options and functionality.

---

For more details refer to the article [How to fetch specific messages in Apache Kafka](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-fetch-specific-messages-in-apache-kafka-4133dad0b4b8)

Comment: If suppose messages fetched with respect to Offset parameter as in the last two cases, will the default offset gets replaced? 
I mean, if we fetch messages by mentioning a particular offset value, and then if I want to fetch from the originally shifted Ofset value, it it possible without having a backup of the previous offset?

Answer (score 2):

Without specifying an offset and partition, you'll only be able to consume next N or first N. To consume in the "middle" of the unbounded stream, you need to give the offset

Other than console consumer, there's kafkacat

First twenty

`kafkacat -C -b -t topic -o earliest -c 20`

And from previous twenty (from partition zero)

`kafkacat -C -b -t topic -P 0 -o -20`

Comment: What is the advantage of using kafkacat over console producer/consumer?

Comment: What is the basic requirement to run a kafkacat in a machine?

Comment: Kafkacat is a C library, so you don't require Java like the other Kafka tools, if you look at its github page, you can find other advantages @Prabhu