# Retrieve last n messages of Kafka consumer from a particular topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-records

kafka version : 0.9.0.1

If `n = 20`,
I have to get last 20 messages of a topic.

I tried with

```java
kafkaConsumer.seekToBeginning();
```

But it retrieves all the messages. I need to get only the last 20 messages.

This topic may have hundreds of thousands of records

```java
public List<JSONObject> consumeMessages(String kafkaTopicName) {
  KafkaConsumer<String, String> kafkaConsumer = null;
  boolean flag = true;
  List<JSONObject> messagesFromKafka = new ArrayList<>();
  int recordCount = 0;
  int i = 0;
  int maxMessagesToReturn = 20;

  Properties props = new Properties();         
  props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
  props.put("group.id", "project.group.id");
  props.put("max.partition.fetch.bytes", "1048576000");
  props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
  props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
  kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);

  kafkaConsumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(kafkaTopicName));
  TopicPartition topicPartition = new TopicPartition(kafkaTopicName, 0);
  LOGGER.info("Subscribed to topic " + kafkaConsumer.listTopics());
  while (flag) {
    // will consume all the messages and store in records
    ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = kafkaConsumer.poll(1000);
    kafkaConsumer.seekToBeginning(topicPartition);

    // getting total records count
    recordCount = records.count();
    LOGGER.info("recordCount " + recordCount);
    for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
      if(record.value() != null) {
        if (i >= recordCount - maxMessagesToReturn) {
          // adding last 20 messages to messagesFromKafka
          LOGGER.info("kafkaMessage "+record.value());
          messagesFromKafka.add(new JSONObject(record.value()));
        }
        i++;
      }
    }
    if (recordCount > 0) {
      flag = false;
    }
  }
  kafkaConsumer.close();
  return messagesFromKafka;
}
```

Comment: Note: lakhs of readers will not understand the term "lakhs". (where, on average, you shouldnt expect more than a few hundred people to actually read your question ... over the next years that is)

Comment: Besides: have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52625995/how-to-fetch-recent-messages-from-kafka-topic ??? I would assume: when `kafka-simple-consumer-shell.sh` can give you first, next, last, ... topics  ... then there should be an API for that, too.

Comment: I am trying for those API's, I didn't found any @GhostCat.

Comment: Will try to make it simpler, you want to consume only recent 20 messages? Or each poll should get max 20 records only?

Comment: Just recent 20 @Deadpool

Comment: And i believe it is always new consumer group? @praveenkumar

Comment: @Deadpool, I am new to kafka.

I am posting my code. Please check it.

Comment: Please don't use "lakh". There's perfectly find non-indian measurements too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `kafkaConsumer.seekToEnd(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions)` to seek to the last offset of the given partition(s). As per the documentation:

> "Seek to the last offset for each of the given partitions. This function evaluates lazily, seeking to the final offset in all partitions only when `poll(Duration)` or `position(TopicPartition)` are called. If no partitions are provided, seek to the final offset for all of the currently assigned partitions."

Then you can retrieve the position of a particular partition using `position(TopicPartition partition)`.

Then you can reduce 20 from it, and use `kafkaConsumer.seek(TopicPartition partition, long offset)` to get to the most recent 20 messages.

Simply,

```
kafkaConsumer.seekToEnd(partitionList);
long endPosition = kafkaConsumer.position(topicPartiton);
long recentMessagesStartPosition = endPosition - maxMessagesToReturn;
kafkaConsumer.seek(topicPartition, recentMessagesStartPosition);
```

Now you can retrieve the most recent 20 messages using `poll()`

This is the simple logic, but if you have multiple partitions, you have to consider those cases as well. I did not try this, but hope you'll get the concept.

Comment: I am not getting last twenty.
Getting middle twenty.
Let assume my record count was 100000.
I am getting records like 61,421 - 61,441. But I want 99,980 - 1,00,000.
I increased 'max.partition.fetch.bytes' value, then it took from 82,525 - 82,845.
It should work irrespective of 'max.partition.fetch.bytes' value

Comment: @praveenkumar try making autoCommit true

Comment: Also, this is no perfect solution either. First, the endPosition will not be the last record offset but the position of the next new record. Second problem is that the logic returns at most 20 records. There are many reasons why there are gaps in the offsets. But the biggest issue is the poll(): What duration should you use when calling the poll()? One second might give you zero records, 1 minute means you are waiting for one minute always.